# How can I relation countries and invoices for print a custom text?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, helper

In the invoice view I have a custom boolean field and a custom text field.

```
 Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 348, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_account_report_invoice_document_with_payments_104
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_103
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons-extra/emb_account/models/account_invoice.py", line 13, in country_group_country_ids
    return self.env['country.group'].search([('name', '=', group)]).mapped('country_ids.id')
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 831, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'country.group'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1686, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1627, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 727, in render_qweb_pdf
    html = self.with_context(context).render_qweb_html(res_ids, data=data)[0]
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 767, in render_qweb_html
    return self.render_template(self.report_name, data), 'html'
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 540, in render_template
    return view_obj.render_template(template, values)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1338, in render_template
    return self.browse(self.get_view_id(template)).render(values, engine)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons/web_editor/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 29, in render
    return super(IrUiView, self).render(values=values, engine=engine, minimal_qcontext=minimal_qcontext)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py", line 1347, in render
    return self.env[engine].render(self.id, qcontext)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_qweb.py", line 59, in render
    result = super(IrQWeb, self).render(id_or_xml_id, values=values, **context)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 275, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 350, in _compiled_fn
    raise e
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 348, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_967_50
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_49
  File "<template>", line 3, in foreach_48
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 355, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.models.qweb.QWebException: 'country.group'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/qweb.py", line 348, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_account_report_invoice_document_with_payments_104
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_103
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons-extra/emb_account/models/account_invoice.py", line 13, in country_group_country_ids
    return self.env['country.group'].search([('name', '=', group)]).mapped('country_ids.id')
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 831, in __getitem__
    return self.registry[model_name]._browse((), self)
  File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 177, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'country.group'

Error to render compiling AST
KeyError: 'country.group'
Template: account.report_invoice_document_with_payments
Path: /templates/t/t/div/t[2]
Node: <t t-set="is_for_emb_message_country" t-value="o.partner_id.country_id and o.partner_id.country_id.id in o.country_group_country_ids('Exportaciones')"/>
```

I'm trying to print in the report the text of my custom field but only if the invoice is going to go to a **country group** i have the id of it.
How can I do the function?
How can I relation countries and invoices to create this?

Comment: Pls your code or what you have attempted for this point.

Comment: I don't have code. I don't know how to connect the country groups with the invoices. I need that connection because if the invoice goes to one country of the country group I need to appear a message in the report

Comment: Describe more about problem with example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67499723/how-can-i-create-this-function-in-odoo-12-or-openerp     this is the best explanation that i can give

Comment: sorry for this question

Comment: `country.group` is not loaded into the database, check if you added the file to the `__init__` file and make sure to update the module.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add a function in account invoice model and call it from the qweb report. You can define a [qweb report parser](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/developer/reference/reports.html#custom-reports) and define it there so it will be available in the report context.

***Example***

I suppose that the country group is defined like following:

```py
class CountryGroup(models.Model):
    _name = 'country.group'

    name = fields.Char()
    country_ids = fields.Many2many("res.country")
```

All you need is to define a function in account invoice model to return the country ids of a specific country group:

```py
class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    def country_group_country_ids(self, group):
        return self.env['country.group'].search([('name', '=', group)]).mapped('country_ids.id')
```

The following code extend the invoice report and show the reference field just after the invoice status for demonstration:

```
<template id="report_invoice_document" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
    <xpath expr="//h2" position="after">
        <t t-if="o.partner_id.country_id and o.partner_id.country_id.id in o.country_group_country_ids('export')">
            <p t-field="o.reference"/>
        </t>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Comment: I updated the question with the error code

Comment: class CountryGroup(models.Model):
    _name = 'country.group'

    name = fields.Char()
    country_ids = fields.Many2many("res.country")
    x_export_message= fields.Text(string="Export Message")

```

Comment: class AccountInvoice(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    x_message=fields.Text(string="Export Message" (related with CountryGroup x_export_message)

Comment: That are the changes I have from your code

Comment: I have that custom field and I need to relation x_export_message to invoice x_message

Comment: Thank you for that code but it's still not working

Comment: I tested the code, and it is working, please update your question and add what you have tried.

Comment: There is the error, I didn't see your message

Comment: The error message tells you that the `emb_dual_use_country` field does not exist. Maybe the file where it is defined is not loaded, or it is defined in the wrong model.

Comment: Here is the code model https://pastebin.com/JHN4H8tW of that

Comment: The code looks fine, make sure that file is imported in `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Yes, all the `__init__.py` files are right

Comment: Do you still get the same error after upgrading your module?

Comment: Did you upgrade the module?